Pynput keyboard listener is working only when the terminals are minimised
I am using the following code to read keyboard events using pynput and publish a suitable msg in ROS2.
import rclpy
from my_interfaces.msg import Chassis
import threading
import time
from pynput import keyboard
import sys

import rclpy.logging

left = 0
right = 0

rclpy.init(args=sys.argv)
node = rclpy.create_node('controller')

pub = node.create_publisher(Chassis, 'cmd_vel', 10)

def publisher():
    global left, right
    msgToSend = Chassis()
    while True:
        msgToSend.left = left
        msgToSend.right = right
        pub.publish(msgToSend)
        time.sleep(0.1)

def on_key_press(key):
    global left, right
    try:
        # Handle key press event
        print('Key is pressed')
        if(key.char == 'w'):
            left = 255
            right = 255

        elif(key.char == 's'):
            left = -255
            right = -255

        elif(key.char == 'a'):
            left = -255
            right = 255

        elif(key.char == 'd'):
            left = 255
            right = -255

    except AttributeError:
        # Some special keys don't have a `char` attribute
        pass

def on_key_release(key):
    # Handle key release event
    global left, right
    try:
        if(key.char == 'w' or key.char =='a' or key.char =='s' or key.char =='d'):
            left = 0
            right = 0

    except AttributeError:
        pass

def listener():
    with keyboard.Listener(
            on_press=on_key_press,
            on_release=on_key_release) as listener:
        listener.join()

def main():
    publisher_thread = threading.Thread(target=publisher)
    publisher_thread.start()
    
    keyboard_thread = threading.Thread(target=listener)
    keyboard_thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

But when I run it in the terminal using ros2 run my_package controller it registers the click only when all the terminals(including the one which echo topic /cmd_vel) are hidden or minimised.
It works as expected when I run it in VS code's debugger or terminal and also when the terminal's always on top is enabled and focus is changed to some other window.
I have tried to not run the keyboard function in a separate thread and call it in the main function but it still didn't work.

Any news on this? It happens the same to me! I think it's probably because the node's console should not receive anything so it get's blocked?
